# react native how to get username or email in android,ios device

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

When my react native app is installed on device i  want to get name Or email of person.

Also I don't want to make user do any login

[There are couple of libraries that only returns device but not any thing related to username or email](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info)

Atleast name is also ok Eg : 'tom'

Comment: On iOS you would need to ask the person what their email address is. There is no way of obtaining it from the device for security and privacy reasons.

Comment: You could use the function `getDeviceName()` of the library you mentioned.
But there is no reliable way to get a real name/email without letting the user enter it.

Comment: @TobiasLins Ohh ! i din't saw that thanks a lott.. can you post that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the function `getDeviceName()` of the library you mentioned ([react-native-device-info](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info)).

But there is no reliable way to get a real name/email without letting the user enter it.